# Does killing Might Sliver before damage affect other slivers' power and toughness?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I got quite confused on what exactly happens in this situation:

Opponent is attacking, he does so with three (3/3) creatures.

I declare blockers, which would be two unimportant (1/1) Slivers and a [Might Sliver](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Might%20Sliver) (2/2). The Might Sliver has a static ability: "All Slivers get +2/+2", so in fact I have two (3/3)'s and one (4/4) creature to block with.

If, after the blockers are declared and before the damage is dealt, the opponent destroys the Might Sliver with an instant (Murder), will my Slivers retain the +2/+2 bonus until damage is dealt, so I would lose three creatures, while he loses two, or is it lost and my defense crumbles and my defenders are all killed?

Comment: When you'd attack with a 1/1 Elvish Pioneer, and it gets blocked by a 2/2 Grizzly Bear, then - before damage is dealt - you would be able to cast Giant Growth on the Pioneer, right? So between bolckers are assigned and damage is dealt, players can change P/T of the creatures on the board. No different with the (removal of) MIght Sliver.

Answer (score 3):

The ability from Might Sliver is a static ability: it functions as long as Might Sliver is on the battlefield.  When the sliver leaves the battlefield (dies in this case), its ability also goes with it.  Your other creatures loose the power/toughness increase.

At the time that your opponent played the instant, it was still in the Declare Blockers step.  During that step, you declare blockers, then both players have a chance to play instants before combat damage. Once your Might Sliver is dead, your other Slivers are 1/1 when you choose to move to damage.

> **604.2.** Static abilities create continuous effects, some of which are prevention effects or replacement effects. These effects are active as long as the permanent with the ability remains on the battlefield and has the ability, or as long as the object with the ability remains in the appropriate zone, as described in rule 112.6.

Comment: I think OP knows that the other slivers lose the +2/+2; the essence of the question is at what point does the P/T become "locked in", i.e. the combat damage step. It should at least be added that players get priority after blockers are declared, and that all P/T changes in that step affect the outcome of the combat damage step.

Comment: Exactly, my point is, when exactly is the bonus is lost, because i've met players  doing it both ways, thats why i made up this example... and the rules themselves don't explain it enough for me.

Comment: @hujuku As the answer says, the bonus is lost when the sliver leaves the battlefield.